# Lets Encrypt ACME-Challenge Apache 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to obtain a Lets Encrypt-Certificate via the webroot directory. I'm running a Ubuntu 16.04 Server with ispconfig.

I have noticed that I cannot reach the acme-challenge folder via the web.

- `http://example.com/` ==> default-host `index.html` is served.
- `http://example.com/.well-known` ==> can be reached and files can be accessed via the web
- `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge` ==> 403, permission denied
- `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html` ==> 404 not found

`.well-known`, `acme-challenge` have root.root and 755. `test.html` has 644

The configuration of the vhost is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
<Directory /var/www/html>
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            # Clear PHP settings of this website
            <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                    SetHandler None
            </FilesMatch>
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
                            Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does someone have a clue why the `acme-challenge` folder is not accessible?

Comment: Did you create the acme-challenge and the test.html file, because certbot deleting this after the challenge.

Comment: Do you have any `.htaccess` files?

Comment: @ Webdesigner I got an error from certbot that the challenge failed. Thus I created the acme-challenge folder manually and placed a test file in there to see if I could access it. @MrWhite: I do not.

Comment: If you happened to have a `mod_md` module installed, try removing or disabling it.